# Echo from bottom to top

Tags: php, mysql

I'm creating something like a forum, and I need the last post to be on top
But I have the last post below

[image]

---

My code:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM community_posts";

$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
if($result-> num_rows > 0){
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)):

echo   '<div class="container">
            <div class="post">
                <!-- HEADER -->
                <div class="header">
                    <img class="post-user-avatar rounded" src="/img/avatars/'.$row['user_avatar'].'" height="50" alt="">
                    <h6 class="post-title"><strong>'.$row['title'].'</strong></h6>
                    <p class="posted-by-date">by <a href="/user/'.$row['user_link'].'">'.$row['user_name'].'</a> at '.$row['date'].'</p>
                </div>
                <!-- BODY -->
                <div class="body">
                    <p class="description">'.$row['description'].'</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>';


    endwhile;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to add a order by on the sql you are executing 
Like this

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM community_posts ORDER BY id DESC";
```

If id is your primary key.

Hope it helps

Comment: This answer assumes that the ID column is the primary key and that this column is an auto_increment column. The OP could also try to order by date (or maybe even last_modified), depending on his/her needs.

Comment: @qvotaxon yes, but OP does not give more information, so we have to assume things.

Comment: I know, I'm just suggesting to add this to the answer for future reference.

Answer (score 1):

Read about what [`ORDER BY`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/order-by-optimization.html) is.

Then, assuming that you have `id` as primary key and set to `auto_increment`, you need to select accordingly:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM community_posts ORDER BY id DESC";
```

Otherwise, order by any relatable column.